# How to use a pipe if a command specifies a file for output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe, zsh

I have command line utility that accepts a file for its output. I want to pipe this output for further processing.

I first tried this:

```
command - | anothercommand
```

But it did not work, it interpreted the - literally. (So it created a file called -)

This did work:

```
command >(anothercommand)
```

Which is fine, but I wonder if it still can be done with a pipe.

I thought of

```
command >(tee) | anothercommand
```

But that only send the output to stdout.

Comment: Does `command | anothercommand` work? Your last example implies that it should.

Comment: No, if I don't specify a file, I get prompted by the program to give a filename for output.

Comment: Oh, right, it's `tee`'s standard output going to `anothercommand`.

Comment: I did not send the output to `anothercommand`, but only to stdout. I think this is because `>(...)` spawns a subshell, to the stdout is not picked up by the pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `/dev/stdout` as your output file:

```
command /dev/stdout | anothercommand
```

Comment: Note that this is only correct because the question is tagged [tag:linux] - it's not portable to other flavours of the Unix family.  And it might still fail if the command expects to `seek()` or `mmap()` its output.

Comment: You are right, it only works in Linux. Other Unixes or Windows are different. Regarding the seek... the question stated that a redirection to another command worked (`>(anothercommand)`), so no seeks involved in this case. Good point anyways for future answer-seekers :-)

Comment: It solved the issue perfectly. I can now use it in Python like this: `res = subprocess.run(['command', '/dev/stdout', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`